# Problem dropdown livewire after wire:navigate

Tags: jquery, laravel-livewire

All dropdown menus in the sidebar and navbar are not working after clicking on URLs containing wire:navigate from Livewire.

When you use wire:navigate in your layout code, Livewire performs a partial navigation, meaning that only part of the page is reloaded. This can cause issues with JavaScript libraries like jQuery and Bootstrap, which rely on specific DOM elements to function properly.

In the case of dropdown menus, they are typically initialized using JavaScript after the page loads. However, when you perform a partial navigation, these DOM elements may be removed and recreated, which causes the JavaScript initialization to be lost.

Comment: To be able to help you, please share some of your code, like how the dropdowns are initialized. Do note the docs state to not rely on `DOMContentLoaded` but instead on `livewire:navigated`